# How to filter by custom object field?

Tags: apex, visualforce, filters, action

Please help. I want to filter fields by Status, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
public class PositionsForJobApplications { 
    
    public List<Position__c> position {get; set;}
    public List<Position__c> StatusTemp;
    
    public PositionsForJobApplications() {
        position = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Open_date__c, Closed_date__c, Min_pay__c, 
        Max_pay__c FROM Position__c];
    }
    
    public List<Position__c> getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    
    public List<SelectOption> statuslist {
        get{
            StatusTemp = [SELECT id, Status__C FROM Position__C];
            statuslist = new List<SelectOption>();
            for(Position__c stat : StatusTemp){
                statuslist.add (new SelectOption (stat.status__c, stat.status__c));
            }
            return statuslist;
        }
        set;
    }
            
    public PageReference save() {
        update position;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="PositionsForJobApplications" lightningStylesheets="true">
    
    <apex:form >
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Positions">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:selectList size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{! statuslist }"/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="StatusTemp" action="{! filter }"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:actionRegion>                
                
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! position }" var="pos">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Positions name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!URLFOR(pos.id)}">{!pos.name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>  
                    <apex:column headerValue="Status">
                        <apex:inputField value="{! pos.Status__c }"/>                    
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Open Date" value="{! pos.Open_date__c }"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Close Date" value="{! pos.Closed_date__c }"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Max Pay" value="{! pos.Max_pay__c }"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Min Pay" value="{! pos.Min_pay__c }"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            
        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to dynamically describe the picklist field options for the `Status__c` field on `Position__c` object. The logic you have is not the correct way to describe options for the picklist field.

You can use the following snippet to describe options for a Picklist field.

```
String fieldName = 'Status__c';
List<SelectOption> picklistOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
// describe the Position__c object and get all fields and then find the relevant field
Schema.SObjectField sObjField = Position__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName);
// describe the field
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = sObjField.getDescribe();
// get picklist options
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : fieldResult.getPicklistValues()){
    picklistOptions.add(
        new SelectOption(
            f.getValue(), f.getLabel()
        )
    );
}
return picklistOptions;
```

You would need to update the `getter` method for the `statuslist` property with above snippet.

Please try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Jagmohan! The picklist returns correctly. But the page is not update with the required values.

Comment: There is the error: 
Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: core.apexpages.el.adapters.ApexListELAdapter